# Gulp watch infinity loop javascript files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify

I'm new Gulp Student, and i made a `watch` to watch if my javascript files changed, run `build-js` task. Simply that. But when i start gulp, he run `build-js` everytime in a infinity loop. What am i doing wrong?

```
gulp.task('build-js', function (cb) {
            pump([
                gulp.src('lib/*.js'),
                uglify(),
                gulp.dest('dist')
            ],
                cb
            );
        });

gulp.task('watch-js', function () {
    gulp.watch('lib/*.js', ['build-js']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['build-js', 'watch-js']);
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: First thing is you need another ) after the } at the end of the 'build-js' task.

Comment: I did it, but nothing changed!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by an "infinit[e] loop"?  I ran your code and it works fine.  The task stays active to watch as it should.  [You should change to cb() but that makes no difference in your case.]

Comment: It works, but everytime in console it says: `starting 'build-js'`... `Finished 'build-js'`...`starting 'build-js'`... `Finished 'build-js'`...`starting 'build-js'`... `Finished 'build-js'`..... Like everytime without changes in code... is that correct?

Comment: No, the only way that might happen is if you watch the destination folder ('dist' in your case) for changes and the changes go back in there.  So a loop but it doesn't look like you have it set up that way.

Comment: I found the error! my final archive `build.js` is inside `dist` folder. He is the infinity loop. How can i tell Gulp to ignore a file? Thanks!!